# How do I test an Nginx reverse proxy locally with multiple services?

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Say I have a website at example.com, and a backend api at example-api.com handled by an Nginx reverse proxy. For one service, I understand that I can update the `/etc/hosts` file to point example.com to 127.0.0.1, but I'm not sure how best to handle local routing for more than one service.

Any help would be greatly appreicated, and I'd be more than happy to clarify my question if anything is confusing.

One thing I tried was including ports in the `etc/hosts` file but I quiclly learned that this is not possible.

Comment: You can probably use host header? Generally, we don't have to add anything to etc/hosts as it is for local dns only. You can also use 1 reverse proxy and multiple ports etc.

Comment: So something like this: `proxy_set_header Host $host;`? And then conditionally route the request based on the host?